# Conditional breakpoint never git hit even if condition is true

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have problem that I cant figure what is wrong. I created simple console app in asp.net and I want to use conditional breakpoint.
Condition is simple
Added breakpoint and add condition: `test == "teststring"`

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string test = "teststring";
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any reeason why conditional breakpoints doesnt work. I try other projects,condition it get never hit.
Visual Studio 17.6.5